# How to quit without saving using just the keyboard?

Tags: ui, keybindings, dialog

When I quit an application (e.g., Excel) with <kbd>Command-Q</kbd>, a dialog box pops up, asking me to select between `don't save`, `cancel` and `save`.
I can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select `save`, or I can navigate the mouse to `don't save`, but how do I get that without the mouse?

On Linux and Windows I can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between the 3 buttons.

What do I do on Mac OS X?

Excel for Mac 2011 (14.3.8)

I tried:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>shift-Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>control-Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>option-Tab</kbd>

No go.

Comment: I suggest you update to latest version 14.4.5 and use the ctrl-tab that was not working in the v 14.3.8!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard shortcut for "Don't Save" in the dialog you mention is <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. The old shortcut, <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, can be restored by issuing the following command in Terminal:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSSavePanelStandardDesktopShortcutOnly -bool YES`

and to revert back,

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSSavePanelStandardDesktopShortcutOnly -bool NO`

In Microsoft Office 2011 for Mac, <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> seems to work by default (but the standard shortcut does not).

Basically, try either <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> for Apple or standard applications, and <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> if that does not work.

Comment: old shortcut? Cmd/D has been standard for as long as I've known. I've never heard of Cmd/del for 'don't save'

Comment: @Tetsujin Apparently Apple made a change with the release of 10.7 (Lion) back in 2011: http://mattgemmell.com/save-sheet-shortcuts-in-lion/

Comment: hmm... makes sense... guess I never noticed at the time & spent a couple of years clicking don't save instead [I must honestly have just slept through the entire period... my best excuse]

Answer (score 8):

It's not the default behavior for tab–I read because someone at Apple felt tabbing "wasn't magical enough"–but in the **Keyboard** preferences, click the **Shortcuts** tab. Then select **All controls** to make the Tab key behave the way you want. Or just press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to toggle this.

[image: because apple hates disabled people]

If you are at the following dialog, just hit <kbd>d</kbd>...no key-combo necessary.
[image]

Comment: Very useful tip. Maybe I'll finally be able to tolerate my Mac

Answer (score 7):

Since Lion, the standard key command for Don't Save is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd> 
Prior to that it was  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>D</kbd>  which some apps still respond to.

[image: dialog]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Tab</kbd>   will switch between the options, which can then be actioned by hitting  <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>  , **only if** you have All Controls set in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts

[image]
[image]