# Save/Don't Save Menus No Longer Respond to Tab and Spacebar (post Big Sur)

Tags: keyboard, big-sur

Prior to Big Sur (OS 11.1), I could use tab to move between the options (buttons) in the type of pop-up menu shown in the image, and spacebar to select an option. For example, in the menu here I could a) press spacebar and have this email 'Save' and b) use tab to transition the highlighted option to 'Don't Save'.

Now, neither of these work, which I don't like bcs. I prefer to use the keyboard. I can't seem to find an option to reenable them (or work around the issue). Any ideas?

[image: big sur save menu]

Comment: I don't know for Big Sur specifically - but see if this is still true (it is to Mojave) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154046/how-to-quit-without-saving-using-just-the-keyboard/154050#154050

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes cmd-backspace/cmd-d still work in Big Sur where they worked before

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked whether following in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts is selected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aivar- yes, I think that was it!

Comment: This is sort of what I wanted... it seems like the "Enter" key is still selecting only the first choice, despite moving the focus. Do you have to use something other than "Enter" to select what is focused?
EDIT: I'm just going to use "command + backspace" to choose "Don't Save" instead of tab/enter.