# How to restore Command D for Don't Save?

Tags: macos, shortcut

Traditionally, the Mac OS (in all its forms) has used <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to trigger "Don't Save" in dialogs that warn you about closing an unsaved file.

That all changed with the 'auto-save' document model, introduced in Lion, at which point <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> moved the file browser's location to the Desktop, and <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd> is the shortcut to "delete" the already auto-saved version of the document.

[image]

However, plenty of apps still don't use Apple's auto-save document paradigm, and have their own dialogs, which still use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for Don't Save.

[image]

For some reason, I've recently been bothered by this discrepancy, and I'm looking for a way to trigger "Delete" with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

The `defaults write` command mentioned in the leading answer here:
[How to quit without saving using just the keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154046/how-to-quit-without-saving-using-just-the-keyboard/154049#154049) doesn't seem to work anymore (Sonoma).

Might someone know of a way of changing the shortcuts in these dialogs?

Comment: I have tried creating custom keyboard shortcuts but I can't make it work.